# Does C# have a method for inserting a string before the extension part of a file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, algorithm

I have a bit of code that is like

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(newFilePath))
 {                
    string suffix = (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond).ToString();
    newFilePath += suffix;
```

but I realized it's incorrect because what I meant to actually do is put suffix before the extension part of the file name (if there is one at all).

Example:

```
C://somefolder/someotherfolder/somepic.jpg  ---> C://somefolder/someotherfolder/somepic0123913123194.jpg
```

Is there a 1-line way to do this, instead of me spending time handrolling a procedure from `lastIndexOf`, `Insert`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple one liner would be:

```
newFilePath = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFilePath),
                            suffix,
                            Path.GetExtension(newFilePath));
```

edit: or to preserve the directory too:

```
newFilePath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}{3}",
                            Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilePath),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFilePath),
                            suffix,
                            Path.GetExtension(newFilePath));
```

Answer (score 2):

`string newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName), suffix, Path.GetExtension(FileName));`

Answer (score 2):

```
newFileName = newFileName.Insert(
    newFileName.Length - Path.GetExtension(newFileName).Length, suffix);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(...);
fileName += suffix + Path.GetExtension(...);
```

Comment: Right idea, wrong details. `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` requires an argument, for obvious reasons, and you will want to re-append the extension.